# pass configuration parameters to services that extends a base service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have a BaseDataService

```
export class BaseDataService {
   public cacheKey: string;

   constructor(public cacheService: CacheService) {}

   //some methods and stuff
}
```

And some of services that extends BaseDataService:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService extends BaseDataService {
   //some methods and stuff
}
```

and

```
@Injectable()
export class VillainService extends BaseDataService {
   //some methods and stuff
}
```

I need to set different values for property cacheKey defined in BaseDataService, and I would like to achieve it doing something like this:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [
      {provide: HeroService, useClass: HeroService, deps:[CacheService, 'cacheKeyForHeroes']},
      {provide: VillainService, useClass: VillainService, deps:[CacheService, 'cacheKeyForVillains']},
      CacheService
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Obviously, this is failing becaouse the second dependency is not Injectable, but I would to know how to pass static configuration to my services.

Thanks to all!

Comment: do you want to pass `cacheKeyForHeroes` string to the `HeroService` through DI mechanism?

Comment: In fact, the mechanism doesn't matter, I need to set that variable a different value for each service...

Comment: like tihs `class VillainService extends BaseDataService { constructor( super(); this.cacheKey='cacheKeyForVillains'`?

Comment: Now I have implemented like this, but I would prefer not to set that property inside each child class but in configuration time, I mean, when the service is declared AppModules. Am I wrong with the way I want to achieve this???

Comment: Probably you could define a factory function like Gunter showed, create an instance inside that function and set the property there and then return that instance. However, that would be very unexpected configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [
      {provide: HeroService, useFactory: () => new HeroService(new CacheService('cacheKeyForHeroes'))},
      {provide: VillainService, useFactory: () => new VillainService(new CacheService('cacheKeyForVillains'))},
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

or

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService extends BaseDataService {
   constructor(HeroCacheService cache) { super(cache); }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class VillainService extends BaseDataService {
   constructor(VillainCacheService cache) { super(cache); }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroCacheService extends CacheService {
  constructor(@Inject('heroCacheKey') key:String) { super(key); }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class VillainCacheService extends CacheService {
  constructor(@Inject('villainCacheKey') key:String) { super(key); }
}

@NgModule({
   providers: [
      HeroService,
      VillainService,
      HeroCacheService,
      VillainCacheService,
      {provide: 'heroCacheKey', useValue: 'cacheKeyForHeroes'},
      {provide: 'villainCacheKey', useValue: 'cacheKeyForVillains'},
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I don't need to extend CacheService, in fact, this is an example only to illustrate that the base service has dependencies. You can imagine the BaseDataService without any dependencies but with a public property that I want to set differently for each child service. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I know you don't need to, but that makes it easier to assign specific configuration values, because DI works well with different types. The part before "or" shows how you can do it without extending.

Comment: mmm... but I cannot pass 'cacheKeyForHeroes' as an argument of CacheService, this is a thirdParty dependency. The class that have cacheKey property is BaseDataService. Maybe, can I pass that value in HeroService & VillainService constructor by using useFactory way?

Comment: I don't understand what "I cannot pass 'cacheKeyForHeroes' as an argument of CacheService, this is a thirdParty dependency" means.

Comment: Found the solution! thanks to your help (answer posted)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You cannot pass a simple string as a dependency of a service. You have to do it like this:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [
      {provide: 'heroCacheKey', useValue: 'heroCacheKeyValue'},
      {provide: HeroService, useClass: HeroService, deps:[CacheService, 'heroCacheKey']},
      {provide: 'villainCacheKey', useValue: 'villainCacheKeyValue'},
      {provide: VillainService, useClass: VillainService, deps:[CacheService, 'villainCacheKey']},
      CacheService
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And modify the BaseDataService like this:

```
export class BaseDataService {

  constructor(public cacheService: CacheService, public cacheKey: string) {}

  //some methods and stuff
}
```

Comment: `deps` are redundant here